# upgrade openssh rpm error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/bin/ssh-keygen: cpio: rename failed - Permission denied

Tags: permissions, rpm, openssh

```
rpm -Uvh openssh-5.3p1-124.el6_10.x86_64.rpm openssh-server-5.3p1-124.el6_10.x86_64.rpm openssh-clients-5.3p1-124.el6_10.x86_64.rpm openssh-askpass-5.3p1-124.el6_10.x86_64.rpm
warning: openssh-5.3p1-124.el6_10.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID fd431d51: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:openssh                ########################################### [ 25%]
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/bin/ssh-keygen: cpio: rename failed - Permission denied
   2:openssh-server         ########################################### [ 50%]
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /etc/pam.d/ssh-keycat: cpio: rename failed - Permission denied
   3:openssh-clients        ########################################### [ 75%]
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/bin/scp: cpio: rename failed - Permission denied
   4:openssh-askpass        ########################################### [100%]
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass: cpio: rename failed - Permission denied
```

Comment: `Permission denied` indicates that you are running the `rpm` command as a normal user. You should either run it as `root` or with `sudo rpm ...`.

Comment: add: I'm running the rpm command as root.

Comment: @Edwardchow, please provide output of `lsattr /usr/bin`.

Comment: find / -name 'ssh*' -exec lsattr {} \;
-------------e- /usr/sbin/sshd
-------------e- /usr/bin/ssh-agent
-------------e- /usr/bin/ssh-keygen;5ce683d2
-------------e- /usr/bin/ssh-keyscan
-------------e- /usr/bin/ssh
-------------e- /usr/bin/ssh-keygen;5ce681cd
-------------e- /usr/bin/ssh-keygen
-------------e- /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id
-------------e- /usr/bin/ssh-add

Comment: @Edwardchow please provide attributes of `/usr/bin` directory instead of `ssh*` files in ther `/` directory.

Comment: the output of lsattr /usr/bin that output is too long, but all output is "-------------e-"